# Extensions of $\mathbb{Z}$ by $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-extensions

Well. My question is very concrete. Does anybody know all the groups $G$ such that it fits in a short exact sequence $1\to \mathbb{Z}\to G\to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 1$, where $\mathbb{Z}_2$ are the integers modulo $2$.

It is well known that such extensions are classified by $H^2(\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z})$, and this cohomology group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Now the trivial element is represented by any semidirect product, and there are just two of them, explicitely: $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2 \cong D_\infty$ the inifnite dihedral group. And the nontrivial element can be represented by $\mathbb{Z}$ clearly.

Is there any extension missing?

Comment: The computation of the cohomology group shows that there are 2 extensions, so you are done?

Comment: I think I am not done with the computation of the cohomology group. Because this classification is not that sharp. For instanse the unit element in the cohomology group represent all the split extensions, i.e., the semidirect products.

Comment: Recall that if $A$ is a $Q$-module, then $H^2(Q,A)$ classifies extensions $1 \to A \to E \to Q \to 1$ such that (!) the induced action of $Q$ on $A$ is the given one. When you write $H^2(\mathbb{Z}/2,\mathbb{Z})$, you have to specify the module structure on $\mathbb{Z}/2$. If its the "canonical" one, the zero element in $H^2$ will correspond to the semidirect product; for the "trivial" one we will get the direct product.

Comment: Oh I see, you are right. The $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action on $\mathbb{Z}$ is fixed. Well anyway, do you know if there is any extension missing, even varying the module structure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are already all extensions.

*Fact.* If $A$ is an abelian group on which a group $Q$ acts, then $H^2(Q,A)$ classifies extensions $0 \to A \to E \to Q \to 0$ where the induced conjugation action of $Q$ on $A$ is the given one.

There are two actions of $Q=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}=\langle t \rangle$ on $A=\mathbb{Z}$, namely $t \mapsto \mathrm{id}$ and $t \mapsto -\mathrm{id}$. Let us call them the "trivial" and the "non-trivial" action and compute $H^2$ in each case.

To compute $H^2(Q,A)$, we use the periodic resolution of $\mathbb{Z}[Q]$-modules
$$\dotsc \xrightarrow{1-t} \mathbb{Z}[Q] \xrightarrow{1+t} \mathbb{Z}[Q] \xrightarrow{1-t} \mathbb{Z}[Q] \to \mathbb{Z}_{\mathrm{triv}} \to 0.$$
Applying $\hom_{\mathbb{Z}[Q]}(-,A)$ shows that $H^2(Q,A) = \ker(1-t : A \to A) / \mathrm{im}(1+t : A \to A)$.

For $A=\mathbb{Z}_{\mathrm{triv}}$ we get $H^2(Q,A) = \ker(0 : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z})/\mathrm{im}(2 : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

For $A=\mathbb{Z}_{\mathrm{non-triv}}$ we get $H^2(Q,A) = \ker(2 : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z})/\mathrm{im}(0 : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z})=0$.

Thus, there are two (isomorphism classes of) extensions of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ by $\mathbb{Z}$ with the trivial action, i.e. central extensions. Since $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{2} \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to 0$ and $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to 0$ are two examples, they must be all. Also, there is a unique extension corresponding to the non-trivial action. Since $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to D_{\infty} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to 0$ is an example, every other extension is isomorphic to this one.